# Disabling buttons

Tags: jquery, button

I need help in disabling two buttons (right/left) in a slideshow when they reach their respective boundaries - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkUYm/); changing the background-color and the cursor type to default would be enough.
This is the jQuery code:

```
var menuItem_place = 0;
var menuItem_position = 0;
var menuItem_limit = parseInt($('.menuItem').length) - 1;

$('.menuItem:first .content').css({margin: 0, height: '100%', lineHeight: '99px'})

$('#rightBtn').on('click', function(){
    if (menuItem_place < menuItem_limit) {
        menuItem_place++;
    }
    menu_animate();
});

$('#leftBtn').on('click', function(){
    if (menuItem_place > 0){
        menuItem_place--;
    }
    menu_animate();
});

var menuitems = $('.menuItem');
var contents = $('.content', menuitems);

menuitems.click(function(){
    menuItem_place = $(this).index();
    menu_animate()
});

function menu_animate() {
    contents.animate({margin: 20, height: '64%', lineHeight: '63px'}, 300);
    $(contents.get(menuItem_place)).stop().animate({margin: 0, height: '100%', lineHeight: '99px'}, 100)
    menuItem_position = 0 - (menuItem_place * 200);
    $('#menuContainer').stop().animate({left: menuItem_position + 'px'}, 300);
}
```

The code is not mine and it's beyond my ability to do what I need. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanx.

Pedro

Comment: Presumably you want button 1 and left button disabled when the slider is all the way to the left and button 4 and right button disabled when the slider is all the way to the right? If so, why not say so? In any case, it's a little rude to just post some (vague) specs and expect people to do your work for you.

Comment: I don't understand the context of the question.

Comment: When do you want to disable?

Comment: Yes, the buttons are to be disabled when the slideshow meets its left/right limits. Sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check `menuItem_place` to see if it's zero (first element) or equal to `$('.menuItem').length - 1` (last element). I created a class (`.disabled`) that is applied or removed based on these conditions.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xkUYm/2/)**

```
var menuItem_place = 0;
var menuItem_position = 0;
var menuItem_limit = parseInt($('.menuItem').length) - 1;
if (menuItem_place == 0) $('#leftBtn').addClass('disabled'); // <-- NEW
$('.menuItem:first .content').css({
    margin: 0,
    height: '100%',
    lineHeight: '99px'
})

$('#rightBtn').on('click', function () {
    if (menuItem_place < menuItem_limit) {
        menuItem_place++;
    }
    menu_animate();
});

$('#leftBtn').on('click', function () {
    if (menuItem_place > 0) {
        menuItem_place--;
    }
    menu_animate();
});

var menuitems = $('.menuItem');
var contents = $('.content', menuitems);

menuitems.click(function () {
    menuItem_place = $(this).index();
    menu_animate()
});

function menu_animate() {
    contents.animate({
        margin: 20,
        height: '64%',
        lineHeight: '63px'
    }, 300);
    $(contents.get(menuItem_place)).stop().animate({
        margin: 0,
        height: '100%',
        lineHeight: '99px'
    }, 100)
    menuItem_position = 0 - (menuItem_place * 200);
    $('#menuContainer').stop().animate({
        left: menuItem_position + 'px'
    }, 300);
    $('#rightBtn,#leftBtn').removeClass('disabled'); // <-- NEW
    if ($('.menuItem').length - 1 == menuItem_place) $('#rightBtn').addClass('disabled'); // <-- NEW
    if (menuItem_place == 0) $('#leftBtn').addClass('disabled');  // <-- NEW
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. However the project I'm working on I can't use a css class/disabled, because I'm doing everything with animated buttons (mouseenter/mouseleave/click) via jQuery and the adaptation is returning unexpected results. I basically replaced your addClass() for my code but it's not good. Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pQ3r/) If you comment all /* NEW */ you'll see the buttons ok. Sorry for the mess. :S

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by disable 2 buttons, but I can only assume you mean the left and right buttons.

I have updated your jsfiddle code, please see below.

http://jsfiddle.net/xkUYm/1/

All I did was to tell them to `display:none` in the css

OR

you could remove them from the HTML all together.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was a little vague before. What I meant was for the Left/Right Buttons to disable themselves after the slideshow reaches its left/right ends.

Comment: Oh right, that makes things a little clearer. You might want to update your original post with that. I also think your question was answered by @j08691 who provided this link [http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xkUYm/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xkUYm/2/)